# Android Studio Add .*so Library Error

Tags: java, android-studio, import, .so

I am adding an image of `build.gradle` and class load library. I am facing the problem:

> Android Studio Add .*so Library Error

build.gradle image :

[image]

class load library :

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.*******.******"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'jniLibs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/core.jar')

}





Error code

    12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.******.******E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.******.**** E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load printer from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.*****.*****-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.*****.*****-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.*****.**** E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.****.******k E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:514)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.****.***** E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.*****.****.printer.PrinterLib.<clinit>(PrinterLib.java:6)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.******.******* E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.*****.*****.printer.PrintService.getImage(PrintService.java:62)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.*****.******E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.********.*****.bt.BtService.printImage(BtService.java:129)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.********.******E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.********.*********.YeniAracParcaBarkodYazdir_Activity$5.onClick(YeniAracParcaBarkodYazdir_Activity.java:192)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.**********.***********E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.*******.******* E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.*********.***** E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.***********.****** E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.**********.**********E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.***********.********** E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.*********.********* E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.************.************ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.************.*********** E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.********.******** E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-05 18:07:28.311 11631-11631/com.********.*********E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**strong text**
```